# Error when i try to run AVD in android studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I get the following error when I run the `AVD.how` to rectify it?

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
```

Output:

```
emulator:

ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

Comment: you need to download and install this from the intel website: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Your computer might not be intel HAXM compatible. If after you have installed the driver it still doesn't work consider trying to use ARM instead because it means your PC's hardware isn't compatible with Intel HAXM. For each OS version there is a ARM version for those computers which can't run HAXM.